# Solr 8.3.0 SynonymGraphFilter and Wildcards

Tags: wildcard, synonym, solr8

is it possible to use wildcards in the synonyms.txt file?
For example

`q:AWS`
synonym.txt looks like `AWS,Webservice*` to match *webservice* and *webservices*.

or `q:changemanagement`
synonym.txt looks like `changemanagement,change manager,chanagemanage*` to match *changemanager* and *changemangerin*.

I want to use the option of the SynonymGraphFilter `expand=false` because with `expand=true` I get too high scores.

My analyzer for index time and query time looks like following:

```
<analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1" types="types.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>

<analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer  class="solr.WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="false" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1" types="types.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

I am not sure if I have to use the SynonymGraphFilter while indexing as well.

Thanks for help!